# How to use angular2 child routes propely?

Tags: angular2-routing

I am working on an angular sample app. The effect I want to get is the following:

I have a login page. When you login, you see the 'home' page. Right now, the home page is a simple html protected by authguard. I want this page to have a header section and body section. This is similar to gmail where the section at the top remain the same for all actions. For eg, the ability to logout appear in the top.

I want couple of routed in this header section that will load the different components in the body section.

This is what I have and does not seem to work.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    , children: [
        {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},            
        { path: 'compb', component: ComponentB, outlet: 'list' },
        { path: 'compa', component: ComponentA, outlet: 'list' }
        ]
},
//{ path: 'compb', component: ComponentB },
//{ path: 'compa', component: ComponentA },    

// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

my home.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<h1>Home</h1>
<p><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a></p>
<p><a [routerLink]="['/compb']">CompB</a></p>
<p><a [routerLink]="['/compa']">CompA</a></p>
<br/><br/>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                Here is starting of the body!
                <router-outlet  name="list"></router-outlet>
                Here is ending of body!
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

compA and compB are simple html pages to display "coponentA here" and "ComponentB here"

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is not working? What *is* working?

Answer (score 0):

After some effort, I got it to work with child routes.

In my app.routes.ts, I initially had :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    , children: [
        {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},            
        { path: 'compb', component: ComponentB, outlet: 'list' },
        { path: 'compa', component: ComponentA, outlet: 'list' }
        ]
},
//{ path: 'compb', component: ComponentB },
//{ path: 'compa', component: ComponentA },    

// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

I changed it to the following:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children:homeRoutes },
//    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
//        , children: [
//            {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},            
//            { path: 'compb', component: ComponentB, outlet: 'list' },
//            { path: 'compa', component: ComponentA, outlet: 'list' }
//            ]
//    },    
    //{ path: 'compb', component: ComponentB },
    //{ path: 'compa', component: ComponentA },    

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

I added the following to home.routes.ts

```
export const homeRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'compa', component: ComponentA },
    { path: 'compb', component: ComponentB },

];
```

In my home.component.html, I added the following:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a></p>
    <p><a [routerLink]="['compb']">CompB</a></p>
    <p><a [routerLink]="['compa']">CompA</a></p>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                <div class="container">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    Here is starting of the body!!<br/>
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    Here is ending of body!!
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```